# Get formatting information in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I'm working on an excel template with formatting, and I'm using python to insert data into the template.

The formatting is turning out REALLY weird. Some of the columns are becoming unformatted, but others later are still formatted, and if I change the textcolor of some columns, then those columns have the rows background color correct, but others don't.

Anyway, it's weird.

What I'd like is a way to see (in a NON WISIWYG way) what Excel thinks it's doing. Maybe something that was vaguely HTML-ish? Decades ago, you used to be able to do this in word processors (I mean like Word Perfect 4.2 era).

Comment: Note: I will not be surprised by the answer of "Nope, you can't do that."

Comment: You may use vba to check properties of the cells (background,  conditional formatting,  table style...)

Comment: Assuming this is a .xlsx file (created by a version of Excel more recent than 2003), it is a collection of XML files compressed into a single file using ZIP. You can change the extension to .zip, extract the files and view them in an XLM editor or even Notepad. It may be hard to find what you are looking for or to make sense of it when you find it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Blackwood already mentioned in the comment, a .xlsx file is just a zip file with a defined folder and file structure. If you want to dig into how Excel stores formatting, rename an Excel file to .zip und unpack it. You will see a structure like this:

```
_rels
docProps
xl
 +-- _rels
 +-- worksheets
 |    +-- sheet1.xml
 +-- sharedStrings.xml
 +-- styles.xml   <-- this is what you are after :-)
 +-- workbook.xml 
[Content_Types].xml
```

If your want to learn about formattinng and styles, examine this file. The general structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<styleSheet 
xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <numFmts />
    <fonts />
    <fills />
    <borders />
    <cellStyleXfs />
    <cellXfs /> 
    <cellStyles />
</styleSheet>
```

I left out the content of each element, but the `numFmts` element stores Number (and Date etc.) formats. Here you also find the internal ID of a format. Let's have a look at the most simple content:

```
    <numFmts count="1">
        <numFmt formatCode="GENERAL" numFmtId="164"/>
    </numFmts>
```

Just the defaults: we have one format, the "GENERAL" format. Fill format and background color are stores in the `fills` element. I made a simple example:

```
    <fills count="1">
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="solid">
                <fgColor rgb="FF00FF00"/>
                <bgColor rgb="FF33CCCC"/>
            </patternFill>
        </fill>
    </fills>
```

Here you see the `patternType` you may specify and color values. Maybe you want to post the Python package you are using, because most packages are able to write such formatting information as well as setting column width. I gave up on templates for my project and write everything directly from Python using a very simple DSL that describes a cell entry in a text line that my script parses. Looks like so:

```
<addr>|<content>|<format>|<alignment>|<color>
example:
  C2|=A2*B2|#0.00|right|#0000FF@#CCCCCC
  A1|"Text"||center|#000000
```

Makes it easy to just have a list of strings in my script and use this as template. I do not need a template anymore and as we have a struct spec for the layout and formatting, no one can accidentally "improve" it. :-)